# Adding elements to an array in C for loop incrementing forever

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to add elements to an array with a for loop in C, however something strange is happening. The i variable is effected by the numbers input using scanf.

```
  int intArray[4];
  int i;
  printf("Input 5 numbers\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    scanf("%d", &intArray[i]);
    printf("i: %d\n",i);
    }
```

Examples of outputs:

[image: Entering only 1's]

[image: Entering only 2's]

And any number greater than 3 input constantly works as intended or any number inserted greater than 3 when i = 3

I don't understand why i changes in this for loop in this way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intArray[4]` has indexes 0, 1, 2, 3. Your for loop's end condition is `i<5`, so it uses index 4, which is past the end of the array, and probably coincides with the variable `i`.

Comment: Ahh I see the error and how to fix it now. But why does this change the "i" variable within the loop? Likewise, why does inputting numbers greater than 3 overcome this problem too?

Comment: Short answer: Undefined behavior is undefined. Longer answer: `intArray[4]` is probably the same piece of memory as `i`, so you're overwriting `i`. As for numbers > 3, interesting. >4 I'd (since i wouldn't be < 5 the loop would stop).

Answer (score 0):

Well, arrays are zero based, so in your case 
i < 5 will result (i from 0 to 4)
which is invalid and out of index, cuz it is supposed to be (i from 0 to 3 - 4 elements)